# mvc partial view ajax update returning the partial view as a page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views, partial-page-refresh

I have a partial view that upon adding an item to the database needs to update.

**The Index.cshtml:**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "WinEntry", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST",      UpdateTargetId = "wingrid", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace}))
{
    @Html.Partial("_winVenue")
    @Html.Partial("_singleWin")
}
<div id="wingrid">
    @Html.Partial("_wingrid")
</div>
```

The _singleWin has the submit button

**The controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Win win)
{
    win.dealerId = "1234567890";
    win.posterid = "chris";
    win.posttime = DateTime.Now;
    wem.addWin(win);
    IEnumerable<Win> w = wem.getVenueWins(win.venue,win.windate);
    return PartialView("_wingrid",w);
}
```

When the controller returns the partial view _wingrid it returns it as a new page and the behavior I am looking for is like an update panel inside the wingrid div.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you included MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftMvcAjax.js in the page you want to update?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already seem to be doing this thanks to the `UpdateTargetId = "wingrid"` option in your AJAX form. Just make sure that you clear values that you modify in your POST controller action form the modelstate. Otherwise HTML helpers could still use the old values:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Win win)
{
    ModelState.Remove("dealerId");
    win.dealerId = "1234567890";
    ModelState.Remove("posterid");
    win.posterid = "chris";
    ModelState.Remove("posttime");
    win.posttime = DateTime.Now;
    wem.addWin(win);
    IEnumerable<Win> w = wem.getVenueWins(win.venue,win.windate);
    return PartialView("_wingrid",w);
}
```

Also don't forget to include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script to your page if you want your `Ajax.*` helpers to work:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, I had it in my layout with some other scripts I consolidated/removed.  When removing I removed unobtrusive.